# Comparing continuous pairs of arrays

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I currently have a program that finds the centroid of a hand. From this center point, 4 lines are drawn to the corners of the frame, top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left [seen Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKMgO.jpg).
My overall goal is to execute a function when the length of these 4 lines are not exhibiting too much change. So far my first plan of action was to find the distance of each corner(4), to the centroid, I have been successful at this by utilizing the distance formula. I so far can see this data updating in real time because of a 1D array with 4 elements [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHCob.jpg). Now my thinking is, the way I will be able to find current change in the distances, is by subtracting the newer distance from the one before. The outputted difference, will then be evaluated using some type of threshold. My main question is how could I do this subtracting thing in which I am able to subtract the newer array from the previous one.

```
from collections import deque
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils
import time
import math
import time, threading
import itertools

def cal_distance(center):

    upper_right_distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(center[0] - 600, 2)) + (math.pow(center[1] - 0, 2)))

    upper_left_distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(center[0] - 0, 2)) + (math.pow(center[1] - 0, 2)))

    lower_left_distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(center[0] - 0, 2)) + (math.pow(center[1] - 600, 2)))

    lower_right_distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(center[0] - 600, 2)) + (math.pow(center[1] - 600, 2)))

    distances = [upper_left_distance, upper_left_distance, lower_left_distance, lower_right_distance]

    return distances

skinLower = (0, 58, 50)
skinUpper = (30, 255, 255)
pts = deque(maxlen=2)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    frame = frame[200 : 500, 550 : 850]

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, skinLower, skinUpper)

    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)

    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

    center = None

    distance = None

    if len(cnts) > 0:
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

    if radius > 10:
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (255, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.line(frame, center, (0, 0), (255, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.line(frame, center, (600, 0), (255, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.line(frame, center, (0, 600), (255, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.line(frame, center, (600, 600), (255, 0, 255), 3)

        distance = cal_distance(center)

        print("updated distance")

        print(distance)

     cv2.imshow('thing', mask)

     cv2.imshow('Original', frame)

     key = cv2.waitKey(1)

     if key == 27:
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Why compute distances to the corners, why not directly determine the distance between the current centroid and the one for the previous frame? Would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the task in following steps:

1) Set a boolean flag or any variable that checks weather its first frame( weather it is calculating the distances for the first time or not)

2) if first time then goto step 3 else go to step 4

3) Read the current frame-> find distances-> store in an array which is named(for e.g) "prevDistances" -> update the boolean flag -> break.

4) Read the current frame -> find distances -> store in an array which is named(for e.g) "currDistances"-> goto step 5.

5) Now you can compare the distance arrays (respective to each element in the array for e.g prevDistances[1]-currDistances[1], .... and check them with the respective thresholds). If the comparisons/subtractions crosses the threshold values then you can continue the desired functionality.